# html2canvas SVG position and size

Tags: svg, html2canvas

I recently discovered html2canvas. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get an SVG to render properly. I am using Chrome but it renders differently (but not how it is displayed) in every browser I have tried.

I have a test project here:
http://psychro.me/html2canvas/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not printed, because the svg has no width and height like this
<svg width="500px" height="500px"